# Cannot deploy JSF application on GlassFish 4 server

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml, glassfish-4, eclipse-jee

Hi I'm new in the JavaServer Faces (JSF) technology and after successfully setting up everything from Eclipse Mars JavaEE over to the GlassFish 4.0 server I ran into the following problem:

I created a Dynamic Web Project and added JavaServer Faces to the configuration after that Eclipse created my project and when I try to deploy the project to my GlassFish server I get the following error message:

```
cannot Deploy JavaServerFaces
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: 
Exception while deploying the app [JavaServerFaces] :
org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId:file:*/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_3_1.xsd; 
lineNumber: 281; columnNumber: 47; 
Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [JavaServerFaces].  
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-commonType' to a(n) 'group' component..
```

When I delete the `web.xml` file from my project I can deploy my project and everything works fine but the problem is then I cannot define any servlet mappings, nor can I set a welcome page...

I would appreciate any help or pointers you can give me to solve this problem.

**UPDATE**

My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

Comment: Show the `web.xml`, it seems like syntax error.

Comment: @PetrMensik Thanks for the reply I added my `web.xml` file. Can you find some syntax errors?

Answer (score 1):

I'll invite you to check this [web.xml validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196877/web-xml-validation-error)
It seem similar to your issue according to the last phrase in the error message