# web.xml showing error after creation , error in javaee.xml

Tags: xml, validation, web.xml

I get the below error in the Line No 2, for the `<web-app declaration>`.

What's wrong with the *web.xml* file below? There is no custom code in the project, just after creation of the dynamic Web Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>LibraryManagement</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />
    <!-- Spring MVC Configurations -->

    <!-- Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[web.xml validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196877/web-xml-validation-error) has the similar question.

```
<web-app  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Hi, Can you also mention the error you got at line#2?

Comment: I put that in the picture added... Compiler says it cannot read the schema document... javaee.xsd

Comment: And sometimes, if I edit web.xml like even add a space or delete a space, sometimes the error goes away... and the project compiles fine